# What criteria would I use to group data based on last working day

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, criteria

I've been scratching my brain over this for a while now.

Pretty amateur coder here using Microsoft Access mostly and have been attempting to make a query for some data which will work out a bonus for staff based on the amount of work they have completed.

I had worked it out to filter the data through criteria based on grouping by month([completiondate]) and multiplying the amount by a value for the types of cases.

However I have been advised that the work month for payroll runs from the last working day of the month to the day before the last working day of the following month.

Is there a way I can create this criteria even in a longer piece of data over the course of a year for example.

I will update this later with more info when I get onto my laptop just don't have it to hand and need to ask before I forget to.

Comment: What difference will it make compared to the calendar month? The very first and/or last days of the month would be non-working days not counted.

Comment: It's the way our payroll system currently works out the timescales for bonuses, it seems counter intuitive to me but I can't change it.

Comment: More details will help for sure, but I think you will end up at MAX(Date), for example if you will do pseudo: MAX((Date-1Month)) and it will give you the last day from the previous month, and then you do MAX((Date))-1 to get the Day before last day of the month. And then you do a quick "verify" to see if it's a working day or a weekend, if a weekend then you reduce the days needed by using WEEKEDAY. Is easier than what it sounds.

Comment: _It's the way our payroll system currently works out the timescales for bonuses_. I understand that, but what bonus will be calculated for weekends and holidays? Zero, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function, passing a date of the current month and one of the next month:

```vb
' Returns the last workday of the month of Date1.
' Optionally, if WorkOnHolidays is True, holidays are regarded as workdays.
'
' Requires table Holiday with list of holidays.
'
' 2022-07-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateWorkdayMonthLast( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal WorkOnHolidays As Boolean) _
    As Date
    
    Dim ResultDate  As Date

    ResultDate = DatePreviousWorkday(DateNextMonthPrimo(Date1), WorkOnHolidays)
    
    DateWorkdayMonthLast = ResultDate

End Function
```

It is an example of how to create a special function using generic functions.

These can be found in my library at **GitHub**: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date). (Too much code to post here).

Comment: Thank you! Using this and your library has helped massively. Appreciate it.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered, if you feel so.